# How do I determine if String value is a Float or a Double datatype?

Tags: typescript, floating-point, double

How do I determine if a given `String` is a `floating point` or `double` data type?

I've already looked through most of Stack Overflow and couldn't find any solution specific to Typescript.

Comment: A string is neither of those. A string is a string.

Comment: @user2357112

My bad. Edited the question to specify Typescript.

Comment: @ErikÅsland - It doesn't matter. TypeScript and JavaScript have the same basic types, and a string is a string regardless. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript (and TypeScript) doesn't have `double` as distinct from "floating point." All floating point numbers — in fact, all non-`BigInt` numbers — are IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point (the type usually called `double`).

So...if it's a string you can convert to number except via the `BigInt` constructor, the resulting number is a floating point `double`.

This is sometimes surprising, because JavaScript has 32-bit `int`/`uint` as a *transient* value sometimes, for instance when handling bitwise operators. But all JavaScript numbers are `double`s once the calculation is complete. (Values in typed arrays have various types, but once they're out of the typed array, they're `double`s.)